# How to select music files from a specific folder like "MyMusic" in RecyclerView

Tags: android

This is my code. It is fetching songs from all directories but i want to get only from specific folder. How can i do it

`

private void readMediaFiles() {
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

```
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String music  = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    Log.d("this123",music.toString());
    String sort  = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + " ASC";
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri,projection,music,null,sort);

    if(cursor != null) {
        Msg.log(String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                @SuppressLint("Range") String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                @SuppressLint("Range") String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                @SuppressLint("Range") String albumid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID));
                mediaListModel = new MediaListModel(Long.parseLong(albumid),path,title);
                mediaListModelArrayList.add(mediaListModel);
            }
        }`
```

Comment: From which folder exactly?

Comment: for example suppose I want to fetch Music files from MY_Music Folder

Comment: Where is that folder located exactly?

Comment: sdcard/music/BGM
here

Comment: Are your files listed now? If yes then what is the .DATA/full path value.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal of fetching only songs from a specific folder by using this approach :

```
String music = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0 AND " +
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE '/mnt/sdcard/Music/SomeArtist/%'";
```

The ***/mnt/sdcard/Music/SomeArtist/*** is where you want to fetch songs only from there.
This limits your managedQuery results to the .../SomeArtist/ dir.

Comment: I have tried like this but its not working for me. Can u please assist more? 
I want to access "sdcard/Music/BGM"

how to exactly used this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String paths = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

        String music = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " !=" + 0
                + " AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA +
                " LIKE '" + paths
                + "/Music/BGM/%'";
        String sort = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + " ASC";
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, music, null, sort);
```